# Set value in a list at given position

Tags: list-manipulation, assignment

Consider

```
r = Array[Total[{##}] &, {3, 3}]
(*{{2, 3, 4}, {3, 4, 5}, {4, 5, 6}}*)
pos = {{1, 1}, {2, 2}};
vals={100,200}
```

This

```
r[[pos[[1]]]]=vals[[1]]
```

doesn't chnage the value of `r` at position `pos[[1]]`? How to achieve this?

(*reads are being performed using `Extract`*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
r[[## & @@ pos[[1]]]] = vals[[1]];
r
```

> ```
> {{100, 3, 4}, {3, 4, 5}, {4, 5, 6}}
> ```

```
r = Array[Plus, {3, 3}];
Do[r[[## & @@ pos[[i]]]] = vals[[i]], {i, 2}];
r
```

> ```
> {{100, 3, 4}, {3, 200, 5}, {4, 5, 6}}
> ```

Additional methods:

```
r = Array[Plus, {3, 3}];
MapThread[(r[[## & @@ #]] = #2) &, {pos, vals}];
r
```

> ```
>  {{100, 3, 4}, {3, 200, 5}, {4, 5, 6}}
> ```

```
r = Array[Plus, {3, 3}];
(r[[#, #2]] = #3) & @@@ (Flatten /@ Transpose[{pos, vals}]);
r
```

> ```
>  {{100, 3, 4}, {3, 200, 5}, {4, 5, 6}}
> ```

```
r = Array[Plus, {3, 3}];
r = SubsetMap[vals &, r, pos];
r
```

> ```
>  {{100, 3, 4}, {3, 200, 5}, {4, 5, 6}}
> ```

```
r = Array[Plus, {3, 3}];
r = MapAt[Last[vals = RotateLeft[vals]] &, pos] @ r;
r
```

> ```
>  {{100, 3, 4}, {3, 200, 5}, {4, 5, 6}}
> ```

Answer (score 4):

`ReplacePart[r, Thread[pos -> vals]]`

Comment: thnx for the sol but this doesn't set the  value of r in place.....rather generates a new one.... is it performant enough to do $r=ReplacePart[r, pos -> val]$ say order `len@r` times for random pos?

Answer (score 1):

```
r = Array[Total[{##}] &, {3, 3}];

pos = {{1, 1}, {2, 2}};

vals = {100, 200};
```

To set the value of `r` in place we can use `ApplyTo` (new in 12.2)
followed by the operator form of `SubsetMap`

```
r //= SubsetMap[vals &, pos];

r
```

{{100, 3, 4}, {3, 200, 5}, {4, 5, 6}}

Comment: may pass `r` directly into `SubsetMap` skipping `ApplyTo`; `SubsetMap[vals &, r, pos]` (as shown in kglr's answer)